# Can we assign UIView object to UIView object of XIB?

Tags: uiview, xib, nib, iboutlet

I have created UIView (say A) object through code and added all the sub views like UIButton, UILabel etc. through code. One other UIView (say B) I have created in XIB. now I am trying to assign A to B. When I Log the sub views of B after assigning, I can see all the sub views of A in B but nothing comes up in the view. I know my logic might be wrong but I didn't get it. Please let me know if its possible or not!

Here is my code:

```
- (UIView*)createButtonView:(NSInteger)viewTag avatarImageName:(NSString*)avatarImageName cardImageName:(NSString*)cardImageName ballImageName:(NSString*)ballImageName
{
    buttonBGView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,86,290,290)];
    buttonBGView.tag = viewTag;

    UIImageView *avatarImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 206, 84, 84)];
    avatarImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:avatarImageName];
    [buttonBGView addSubview:avatarImageView];

    UIButton *temoCardButton  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 42, 188, 222)];
    temoCardButton.tag = viewTag;
    [temoCardButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:cardImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [temoCardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cardButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonBGView addSubview:temoCardButton];

    UILabel *scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(228, 0, 30, 30)];
    scoreLabel.text = [cardPointsArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    scoreLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [buttonBGView addSubview:scoreLabel];

    buttonBGView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    return buttonBGView;
}


-(void)cardButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[buttonBGView subviews]);

    self.cardTappedView = buttonBGView;

    NSLog(@"%@",[self.cardTappedView subviews]);
}
```

**Thanks**